# jOOQ PlainSQL custom keywords / custom dialect

Tags: jooq

I'm using jOOQ to generate PlainSQL queries, that mostly follow ANSI SQL.
What if I'm dealing with a SQL statement for a field, that needs to be parsed to verify if it's correct SQL (I'm using `DSL.using(SQLDialect.DEFAULT).parser().parseField(sqlString)`), but the resulting sql from this field should use the platform native syntax and keywords?

Consider an example SQL statement for a field `TO_HEX(SHA256(CAST(userId AS string)))` (note that I've set the `DSLContext` to ignore unknown functions).
When parsing this using `parseField` and inspecting the resulting SQL, this is transformed into `to_hex(SHA256(cast(userId as varchar)))`. The target platform however, does not support `varchar`. Is there any option to specify how e.g. a cast like this should be rendered? I've looked into the documentation, but I can't seem to find how to override specific keywords / define my own dialect.

Comment: I've provided an answer about how this can be done in general. If you have specific follow up questions about individual functions, I'll be happy to answer them here as well (ideally as new Stack Overflow questions).

Comment: Thanks @LukasEder, we'll give your approach a try and we'll let you know!

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 dialects you should configure:

- The dialect you're passing to `DSL.using()` (corresponding to [`Configuration.dialect()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Configuration.html#dialect())) is the *output* dialect, i.e. you should set that to your target dialect
- The [`Settings.parseDialect`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#parseDialect) is the *input* dialect. If your dialect isn't supported, you can leave this untouched.

If you need to support custom syntax in the parser, there's a [`ParseListener` SPI](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/sql-parser-listener/), which allows for overriding input/output behaviour for certain syntax elements. You can't use this to override *everything*, but it should work at least for:

- `Field` expressions
- `Condition` expressions
- `Table` expressions